# How to query this result in SQL? or maybe in python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a table with multiple user_id and each one can redeem a discount code like this:

| user_id | discount_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |

I have to count the overlap of users for each discount code.

I think this should be the result:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select t1.discount_code, t2.discount_code code, count(distinct t1.user_id) value
  from your_table t1
  join your_table t2
  using(user_id)
  group by 1, 2
)
pivot (any_value(value) for code in ('A', 'B'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried?